# Facebook custom unit for Fitness is not showing

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I am currently implementing a Facebook Fitness sharing feature and I would like to have a custom unit just like what nike do:

[image]

I have hosted my own unit object and implemented the share button using the following code:

```
 iv_workout_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Create an object
                    ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("fb:app_id", "xxxxx")
                    .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
                    .putString("og:title", "example")

                    .putString("fitness:duration:value", (workout.duration / 1000) + "")
                    .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")

                    .putString("fitness:distance:value", String.format("%.2f", workout.current_distance / 1000f))
                    .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")

                    .putString("fitness:speed:value", (workout.current_distance / (workout.duration / 1000)) + "")
                    .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")

                    .putString("fitness:custom_unit_energy:value", 100 + "")
                    .putString("fitness:custom_unit_energy:units", "http://example.com/fatburn.html");


            for (int i = 0; i < workout.location_record.size(); i++) {

                object.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:latitude", workout.location_record.get(i).getLat());
                object.putDouble("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:location:longitude",workout.location_record.get(i).getLong());

                if(i == 0) {
                    object.putString("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:timestamp", workout.timestamp - workout.duration + "");
                }else {

                    if (i == workout.location_record.size() - 1) {
                        object.putString("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:timestamp", workout.timestamp + "");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Create an action
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("fitness.runs")
                    .putObject("course", object.build())
                    .build();

            // Create the content
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName("course")
                    .setAction(action)
                    .build();


            ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog((Activity) context);
            shareDialog.show(content);
        }
    });
```

And for http://example.com/fatburn.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="381721038699445" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="fitness.unit" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="http://exanple.com/fatburn.html" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Fat Burn" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
<!-- Developer defined fitness unit name -->
<meta property="fitness:name" content="Fatburn"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I click the share button, the Facebook share dialog pop up and I press the post button, a toast pop up telling me that the post is shared.

But nothing show on my wall...

Did I missed anything in my code?

Comment: Can you check if *anything* is posted, i.e. that also nothing appears in your Facebook activity log? Also, please add to your question which SDK version you are using.

Comment: Thanks @derabbink, I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my research, I have to host my own object, just like what I did in update 2.

But the reason it is not working is that I have something wrong in my object.

I use the following tool to validate the object and fix it according to the instruction it gives, then my code works!

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/